# Leaflet - tell whether an object a layer or a group

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to close popups on an object, but I don't know whether it is a layer or a geoJSON (and hence a feature group). If the former, I can do `layer.closePopup()`, but if the latter, I have to do `layer.eachLayer().closePopup()` (I think).

How do I test whether an object in Leaflet is a layer or a group? I'm getting some joy with `if (layer.childNodes)`, but it doesn't always seem to work, and I'd rather have a Leaflet solution than a DOM one, as I think it would be more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using javascript to test if the function is defined:

```
if (typeof layer.closePopup == 'function') {
    layer.closePopup()
} else {
    layer.eachLayer(function(layer) { layer.closePopup() })
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. In lieu of a Leaflet API answer, I'm very happy to accept this method.

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript's [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
if (layer instanceof L.LayerGroup) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

L.LayerGroup can contain other LayerGroups, pretty confusing. I made this generic solution for recursively traversing a layergroup in my app ('vg.Map.' are just namespaces):

```
/*  vg.Map.recurseLayerGroup
    Run recursively through L.LayerGroup until contained layers are no
    longer instances of L.LayerGroup, then execute callback function.

    Parameters:
    o.layer - L.LayerGroup instance to examine.
    o.done - callback function to execute on non-layergroup instances.
      receives one argument, the layer instance.
*/
vg.Map.recurseLayerGroup = function(o){
  var o = o || {};
  o.done = typeof o.done === 'function' ? o.done : 
    function(lr){vg.log('console.Map.recurseLayerGroup done',lr);};
  var go = function(lr1){
    if(lr1 instanceof L.LayerGroup){
      // console.log('vg.Map.recurseLayerGroup instanceof true');
      lr1.eachLayer(function(lr2){ 
        go(lr2); 
      });
    } else {
      // console.log('vg.Map.recurseLayerGroup instanceof false');
      o.done(lr1);
    }
  };
  go(o.layer);
};
```

Then pass in appropriate callback function from elsewhere in the app:

```
  var lgDone = function(lr){
    lr instanceof L.Marker ? lr.setIcon(vg.Map.Icon.Default) :0;
  };
  myLayer instanceof L.LayerGroup ? vg.Map.recurseLayerGroup({layer:myLayer, done:lgDone}) :0;
```